# gradients with respect to a repeating function

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm having trouble computing gradients for a transition function being repeatedly called.

Gradients being computed w/ respect to actions are None even though the loss depends on the selected actions chosen by a sum of the max values generated from repeated transition calls. If we change the value of the loss function to be a sum over v instead of a then we receive gradients for the transition.

Why is it the case that there are no gradients being computed for the transition when our loss is computed w/ respect to a sum over a?

Below is a chunk of sample code where you can replicate the issue.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

ACTION_DIM = 1

# random input
x = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(1, 5))  # [b branches, state_dim]

depth = 3
b = 4
v_list, a_list = [], []  # value and action store
# make value estimates 3 steps into the future by predicting intermediate states
for i in range(depth):
    reuse = True if i > 0 else False
    x = tf.tile(x, [b, 1])  # copy the state to be used for b different actions
    mu = tf.layers.dense(x, ACTION_DIM, name='mu', reuse=reuse)
    action_distribution = tf.distributions.Normal(loc=mu, scale=tf.ones_like(mu))
    a = tf.reshape(action_distribution.sample(1), [-1, ACTION_DIM])
    x_a = tf.concat([x, a], axis=1)  # concatenate action and state
    x = tf.layers.dense(x_a, x.shape[-1], name='transition', reuse=reuse)  # next state s'
    v = tf.layers.dense(x, 1, name='value', reuse=reuse)  # value of s'
    v_list.append(tf.reshape(v, [-1, b ** i]))
    a_list.append(tf.reshape(a, [-1, b ** i]))

# backup our sum of max values along trajectory
sum_v = [None]*depth
sum_v[-1] = v_list[-1]
for i in reversed(range(depth)):
    max_v_i = tf.reduce_max(v_list[i], axis=1)
    if i > 0:
        sum_v[i-1] = tf.reduce_max(v_list[i-1], axis=1) + max_v_i

max_idx = tf.reshape(tf.argmax(sum_v[0]), [-1, 1])
v = tf.gather_nd(v_list[0], max_idx)
a = tf.gather_nd(a_list[0], max_idx)
loss = -tf.reduce_sum(a)
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
grads = opt.compute_gradients(loss)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue stems from your `arg_max` call in defining `col_idx`. `Arg_max` is a positional argument, and as such has no gradients. This makes sense, because the position of the maximum in a list does not change as the maximum changes.

I am also not convinced that the call to `tf.contrib.distributions.Normal` will have derivatives with respect to its input variables, but only because it is in contrib. Perhaps you could try using the default tensorflow one if the troubles persist after fixing the `arg_max`.

Comment: argmax gradient would be "channeling" the gradients only through the max input path. For further reference a nice discussion was held here: https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/4e2get/argmax_differentiable/

Comment: That's a great explanation you referenced, but I don't agree with your take-away. I believe they're saying that the `max` operation channels the gradients through the max input path, but the `argmax` operation does not. That's what we would expect, since the derivative of the max of a tensor changes linearly as the max changes. The position of the max does not, and as such should not have gradients defined.

Comment: You are right. Sorry I was not quick enough to fully grasp your first post and thank you for taking the time to set things straight.